# Finding INITEX?

Tags: tex-core

In the file `plain.tex`, in many places there are references like

> % When INITEX (the TeX initializer) starts up,
>   % it has defined the following \catcode values:
>   % \catcode`\^^@=9 % ascii null is ignored
>   ...

and

> % INITEX sets up \mathcode x=x, for x=0..255, except that
>   % \mathcode x=x+"7100, for x = `A to `Z and `a to `z;
>   % \mathcode x=x+"7000, for x = `0 to `9.

, for instance.

Where are these INITEX definitions located at?

Comment: Here's a start: [What’s happened to *initex*?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=initex)

Comment: My [LuaTeX based software](https://github.com/speedata/publisher/blob/develop/bin/sprun#L132) is called with `luatex --ini`, because I don't need all the extra plain macros :)

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: Cool! `:-)` Does that mean you only use the primitives?

Comment: @morbusg - actually [the TeX file](https://github.com/speedata/publisher/blob/develop/src/tex/publisher.tex) is only a few lines long. The rest is about manipulating Lua nodes to create a page (see [TeX without TeX on the Lua wiki](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/TeX_without_TeX)). So while I use TeX in the strict sense, I don't use the TeX programming language, and therefore I don't need any macros. Just a few PDF helpers (bookmarks and colorstack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INITEX` is a slightly modified version of `tex` suitable for creating format definitions; as such, it starts with a very blank slate.  Its starting state is described in the TeXbook, p.39:

> There's a program called `INITEX` that is used to install TeX, starting from scratch; `INITEX` is like TeX except that it can do even more things....`INITEX` needs extra space to carry out such tasks [hyphenation tables, formats], so it generally has less memory available for typesetting....
>
> When `INITEX` begins, it knows nothing but TeX's primitives.  All 256 characters are initially of category 12, except that `<return>` has category 5, `<space>` has category 10, `<null>` has category 9, `<delete>` has category 15, the 52 letters `A...Z` and `a...z` have category 11, `%` and `\` have the respective categories 14 and 0.

So the answer to your question is that these definitions are made in the TeX source code; I do not have `TeX: the program` at hand right now, so I can't give you a line number.

These days, there <strike>is</strike> may be no actual program called `initex` on your computer; instead, as [the TeX FAQ explains](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-initex), it is incorporated into `tex` itself via  command-line options.

Comment: My distribution of TeX Live 2011 still carries `initex.exe`...

Comment: With MikTeX you find both initex as well as virtex, which is something akin to his wife:)

Comment: @Werner TeX Live binaries (and probably some other distributions too) have the ability to look at their name to deduce how to behave, e.g., if you link or copy the `tex` binary to `initex` it will behave like `tex -ini` which is the most distribution work these days.

Comment: @Ryan: By `TeX: the program`, do you mean the `weave`d result (i.e., `tex.pdf`)?

Comment: @morbusg: No, I mean the book by that name which is volume 2 of the "Computers and Typesetting" series of which volume 1 is my copy of the TeXbook.  I suppose `tex.pdf` would also do and is probably the same thing.