LaTeX3 with catcode changes
This worked years ago where l3cctab was an own package. It is now included into expl3:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cctab_new:N \l_ctx_cctab  
\cctab_gset:Nn \l_ctx_cctab
{
    \char_set_catcode_group_begin:n     { `\[ }  % [
    \char_set_catcode_group_end:n       { `\] }  % ]
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n          { `\{ }  % {
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n          { `\} }  % }
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n          { `\! }  % !
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n          { `\? }  % ?
    \char_set_catcode_space:n           { 32 }
}

\cctab_new:N \l_my_cctab
\cctab_gset:Nn \l_my_cctab
{
    \char_set_catcode_comment:n        { `\#} 
    \char_set_catcode_parameter:n      { `\%}  
    \char_set_catcode_space:n          { 32 } 
}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment { Spezial }{ m }
{ \expandafter\cctab_begin:N \csname l_#1_cctab\endcsname}
{ \cctab_end:\par }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Normaler Text mit einigen Wörtern % Standard Catcode

\ExplSyntaxOn
Normaler Text mit einigen Wörtern % Latex3 

\begin{Spezial}{ctx}
\def\!foo?#1[foo und #1]    % Macroname is \!foo?
\!foo?[bar]
\end[Spezial]                 

\begin{Spezial}{my}
\% and \# are changed.
     
\def\foo%1{foo und %1}                               
\foo{bar}
\end{Spezial}         

\end{document}

Now I get with up-to-date TL24 and `pdflatex?
! Use of \!foo? doesn't match its definition.
l.37 \!foo?[
          bar]


I'm not yet sure why, but # has category 12 inside of your ctx environment.

@Skillmon I wanted to say that

@DavidCarlisle is # hardcoded as category 6 in IniTeX? If not that's the reason, cctab is documented to set the categories to those of IniTeX, then apply the user made changes, and save that for later reuse.

@Skillmon looks like an answer to me

$ tex --ini '\showthe\catcode`#'
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2024) (INITEX)






You want a starting point different from INITEX.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cctab_new:N \g_ctx_cctab  
\cctab_new:N \g_my_cctab

\cctab_gset:Nn \g_ctx_cctab
  {
    \cctab_select:N \c_document_cctab
    \char_set_catcode_group_begin:n     { `\[ }  % [
    \char_set_catcode_group_end:n       { `\] }  % ]
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n          { `\{ }  % {
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n          { `\} }  % }
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n          { `\! }  % !
    \char_set_catcode_letter:n          { `\? }  % ?
    %\char_set_catcode_space:n           { 32 }
  }

\cctab_gset:Nn \g_my_cctab
  {
    \cctab_select:N \c_document_cctab
    \char_set_catcode_comment:n        { `\#} 
    \char_set_catcode_parameter:n      { `\%}  
    %\char_set_catcode_space:n          { 32 } 
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment { Spezial }{ m }
  { \cctab_begin:c {g_#1_cctab} }
  { \cctab_end:\par }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Normaler Text mit einigen Wörtern % Standard Catcode

\ExplSyntaxOn
Normaler Text mit einigen Wörtern % Latex3 

\par

\begin{Spezial}{ctx}
\def\!foo?#1[foo und #1]    % Macroname is \!foo?
\!foo?[bar]
\end[Spezial]                 

\begin{Spezial}{my}
\% and \# are changed.
     
\def\foo%1{foo und %1}                               
\foo{bar}
\end{Spezial}         

\end{document}



Variables that are set globally should be prefixed by \g_
No \expandafter, please.


From the documentation of l3cctab, function \cctab_gset:Nn:

Starting from the iniTEX category codes, [...]

Now from the TeXbook (quote and its formatting taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46538/117050):

When INITEX begins, it knows nothing but TeX's primitives.  All 256 characters are initially of category 12, except that <return> has category 5, <space> has category 10, <null> has category 9, <delete> has category 15, the 52 letters A...Z and a...z have category 11, % and \ have the respective categories 14 and 0.

So this is expected behaviour, since # is of category code 12 in iniTeX and you need to assign it any other category it should have.
If your code was running earlier that was either a bug, or a deliberate change in cctab. The wording in the documentation referring to iniTeX as the starting state of a cctab is from 2020-07-10, so now more than 4 years old, if your code worked in the meantime it was a bug.

Could you clarify If your code worked in the meantime it was a bug? Did the OP exploit a bug that has since been corrected in the underlying code, or was the bug in OP's code? Unrelated to the question, I recall that I once did something that worked, only because I inadvertently exploited a bug.

@rallg if the exact code of OP worked in the last four years then there was a bug in cctab that has been corrected in the meantime (since the documentation says it should've that behaviour for at least 4 years now). I'm not sure what the exact documentation was when it was still an experimental package (and I don't feel that there's a need to dig through the git repo).

it worked in sep 2019.
